# I need .PPD Cups driver for Canon E410?

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

The printer have stable driver for Mac, but doesnt have linux driver.

since Mac and Linux have same `.PPD ghostscript`. I think they are available. Where can I find it?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190  search it here by model id

Comment: http://support-in.canon-asia.com/contents/IN/EN/0100764002.html canon e410 drivers for mac

Comment: thats mac format i cant even extract anything

Comment: you said mac and Linux used same `.ppd` files, i just searched i found `.ppd`. but unfortunately I can't answer that, maybe some other user will

Comment: Yes the .ppd high posibility is same, but that driver is Mac encrypted (.pkg) so it can't be accessed

Answer (score 0):

The `cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz` driver from Canon seems to be the core file for all their new pixma multi-function devices; I would be curious to know if one installed it; if it would drive this E410

one gets it from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100626502.html and one downloads and SAVES it so it should end up in the Downloads folder

commands to install are: .. line by line, hitting the ENTER key after each paste ..

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

I apologise for not answering directly; but if it worked, it would be very helpful

I see that for the E460, this is the package Canon recommend

---

Comment: CNijfilter is work for old product. latest product use .ppd to make their printer MAC/network compatible.